# Sum rule and dense limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, conductors, lattice-model

Is the finite size of lattice constant important for derivation of sum rules, for example, the sum rule for diagonal conductivity $\sigma_{xx}$: 
$$
\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega\sigma_{xx}(\omega) = \frac{\omega_{p}^{2}}{8}?
$$

Comment: What is the definition of $\omega_p$?

Comment: @fs137 : this is plasma frequency.

Comment: OK, and the plasma frequency depends on the lattice spacing through the density of conduction electrons. In general, under what conditions will a response function $\chi(\omega)$ be integrable?

Comment: @fs137 : by using (seems to be general) expression
$$
\chi (\omega , \mathbf q) = \sum_{n}\langle 0|\hat{\rho}_{\mathbf q}|n\rangle \frac{2(E_{n} - E_{0})}{\omega^{2} - (E_{n} - E_{0})^{2}+i0},
$$
where $\hat{\rho}$ is density operator, I can't give an answer.

Comment: @fs137 : sorry, I'm very bad in linear response formalism, and don't understand Your statement. Could You make it more clear, please?

Comment: The scales that are relevant to a system control the allowed behavior of response functions like $\sigma_{xx}(\omega)$, the idea being that each characteristic scale $a_\alpha$ can be associated with characteristic frequency (or frequencies) $\omega_\alpha$ through the speed(s) at which waves propagate. [Typically there are only a finite number of wave propagation speeds, corresponding to transport of photons or phonons].   In order for a sum rule to make sense, the behavior of $\sigma_{xx}(\omega)$ must allow for sufficiently rapid decay as $|\omega|\rightarrow\infty$ and sufficient...

Comment: ... regularity near $\omega=0$. This means that response functions tend to require either some sort of cutoff at high frequency (typically set by a lattice spacing), or low frequency (typically set by the sample volume) in order to be integrable. Lattice structure can also control features of response functions $\sigma_{xx}(\omega)$ at intermediate frequencies (like cusps, and local extrema).

Comment: @fs137 : "...This means that response functions tend to require either some sort of cutoff at high frequency (typically set by a lattice spacing), or low frequency (typically set by the sample volume) in order to be integrable...", - typically the plasma frequency is infinite when size of lattice tends to zero, right? This means that the right handside of the sum rule tends to infinity, and thus the conductivity in $\omega $ space isn't integrable. In the result the sum rule doesn't make sense, am I right?

Comment: @fs137 : I'm also not sure in the statement that $\omega_{p}$ tends to $\infty$ as $a \to 0$, where $a$ is the lattice constant.

Comment: So, $\omega_p$ goes as the square root of the number density of conduction electrons $n_e$. Assuming each ion in the lattice contributes a fixed number of conduction electrons, $n_e$ is proportional to the ion density $n_i$. If $a\rightarrow 0$, then $n_i$ (and hence $n_e$ and $\omega_p$) becomes infinite.